# CI Datamapper ORM complex count related

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

For the first time, I'm using a [datamapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu) for a CodeIgniter project.

I have a table `products`, in which I store my items.
There is a table `categories`, that specifies the kind of item.
And a table `brands`, so we know which brand a product item belongs to.
There are join tables for `brands_products` and `categories_products`.

I want to be able to know how many products we have for each brand in a specific category.
It would result in something like this:

```
Category A:
- brand 1 (6 products)
- brand 2 (4 products)
- brand 3 (7 products)
```

I started with something like this:

```
$products = new Product();

$products->where_related_category('url', $this->uri->segment(3))
     ->order_by('brands.name')
     ->include_related('brand', array('id', 'name', 'url'), true, true)
     ->get();
```

But of course, this doesn't make the count work. I'm kind of blinded to see te obvious solution, I guess ... Any ideas?

Comment: What are the specific errors/malfunctions you're getting? Wrong count? PHP errors? MySQL errors?

Comment: Well, I tried to manage a count in, but I can't figure it out to get the result. I want a productcount per brand, not all products in one count, not all brands ...

Comment: Did you try using [`include_related_count()`](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/getadvanced.html#include_related_count) instead of `include_related`?

Comment: Id dit, but all it did was counting how many brands each product has ..

Comment: Hmmm, how about grouping what you already have by brand [`group_by()`](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/get.html#group_by)?

Comment: Tried it too, but it doesn't count the number of products per brand `$products ->where_related_category('url', $this->uri->segment(3)) ->order_by('brands.name') ->include_related_count('brand') ->include_related('brand', array('name', 'id'), true, true) ->group_by('brands.name') ->get();`